# git bash on windows 10 reports "fatal: AggregateException encountered.One or more errors occurred" while trying to push or pull to GitHub

Tags: git, ssl, github

Please find the trace below for "git pull" command. I am not able to find the reason for the fatal error from the trace other than noticing that "github.com is not found in _netrc file". Is it the reason for fatal error? Or anything else that I may be missing. Please suggest how to avoid this error?

```
    $ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
    10:26:30.461367 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'pull'
    10:26:30.465364 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
    10:26:30.512336 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
    10:26:30.517352 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/cupendra/sblweb.git'
    * Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
    * timeout on name lookup is not supported
    *   Trying 192.30.253.113...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to github.com (192.30.253.113) port 443 (#0)
    * ALPN, offering http/1.1
    * Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      CApath: none
    * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
    * Server certificate:
    *  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=5157550; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
    *  start date: May  8 00:00:00 2018 GMT
    *  expire date: Jun  3 12:00:00 2020 GMT
    *  subjectAltName: host "github.com" matched cert's "github.com"
    *  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
    *  SSL certificate verify ok.
     GET /cupendra/sblweb.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
    Host: github.com
    User-Agent: git/2.12.0.windows.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
    Pragma: no-cache

     HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
     Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
     Content-Type: text/plain
     Content-Length: 21
     WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
     X-GitHub-Request-Id: EA36:2AFA:43AFBBD:7B6E89B:5BE66500
     X-Frame-Options: DENY

    * Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
    10:26:32.732095 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
    10:26:32.929007 git.c:596               trace: exec: 'git-credential-manager' 'get'
    10:26:32.930006 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-credential-manager' 'get'
    fatal: AggregateException encountered.
       One or more errors occurred.
    10:26:34.254011 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'bash' '-c' 'cat /dev/tty && read -r line /dev/tty && echo "$line"'
    Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Comment: What is the output without all the tracing enabled?

Comment: Just the fatal error and a prompt asking for username. However, if I enter username and password things work normal. I am just curious to know what is causing this error and how to avoid incase if it causes any major problem in future.

fatal: AggregateException encountered.
   One or more errors occurred.
Username for 'https://github.com':

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/57

Comment: Unfortunately, that link did not solve the problem I face. Thanks anyway.